# Why the $PATH of my container is different when I execute a command outside the container?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, containers

When I execute the `which python3` command outside the container, this is the result:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

But when i am inside the running container this is the result:

```
root@3d95a2c1307c:/# which python3
/local//Miniconda3/bin/python3
```

I want to use the Python located in the second path. What is going on? I included this step on the dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH=/local/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the image you use for your container (which is not clear at all in your questions), you might have different or custom $PATH, and respectively different python executable path..
So if the container's $PATH accommodates a custom path for python. maybe that is what it needs to correctly run the image.. again not clear in your Question.

Comment: This is the commands I used in order to install Conda and download Python3`chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $INSTALL_DIR/Miniconda3/

export PATH=$INSTALL_DIR/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH

echo export PATH=$INSTALL_DIR/Miniconda3/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc          conda install -y python=3.8.0`   AS I said, inside the container it works fine. Why when I exewcute the same command outside the container ittake another Python path?

Comment: Most paths to running a Docker container don't use a `.bashrc` file, and many images don't contain bash at all.  Use the Dockerfile [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive instead.